# Como fazer link para download de arquivo em html?

Tags: html, python, django

Eu estou usando a tag:

```
<a href:"{{ arquivo.caminho }}" download>link</a>
```

com o atributo download para fazer um download link de arquivos da minha rede local (imagens tiff), porém, o arquivo baixado é um arquivo .tiff contendo o html da minha página.
Também percebi que o link de donwload retornado é prefixado pelo endereço do meu servidor django:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/172.23.5.17/Imagens/etc...

meu código html:

```
<tr>
  <td id="td_result"><p class="resultados_p">{{ resultado.nome }}</p></td>

  <td>
    <a href="resultado.download" download>
      <div class="download"></div>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

valor do resultado.download:

> \\172.23.5.17\Imagens\landsat\IMAGENS_LANDSAT_8_2017\Processadas\003_068l8_oli_002065_20140803_b654_fuseo_sirgas2000_utm.tiff

(já experimentei mudar as barras)

Link retornado pela página:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/172.23.5.17/Imagens/landsat/IMAGENS_LANDSAT_8_2017/Processadas/003_068l8_oli_002065_20140803_b654_fuseo_sirgas2000_utm.tiff

Comment: Em: <a href="resultado.download" download> leia-se <a href="{{ resultado.download }}" download>

Answer (score 3):

Nem o Django, nem nenhum framework mantido de Python tem uma correspondência automatica entre caminhos de arquivos no servidor e URLs - isso é algo de HTML estático que vem da Web pré-1.0 - e é algo que acontece em aplicações CGI, ou em tecnologias como PHP ou Asp.

O que você precisa por no `href` da sua página é o endereço para uma view, como qualquer outra view em Django. O código *dessa* view é que vai retornar, em vez de HTML, um arquivo de imagem, que vai marcado como tal nos cabeçalhos HTTP. (O framework faz isso automaticamente).

Dentro do código Python desta view, você pode optar por corresponder o caminho que vem na URL diretamente a arquvos no disco, embora isso seja uma péssima prática de segurança. As tecnologias que fazem isso por padrão levaram *anos* para fechar todas (se é que não sobrou alguma) falhas de segurança derivadas disso (por exemplo, o usuário ao colocar diretórios com o nome de ".." na URL podiam acessar qualquer arquivo visível pelo processo do servidor HTTP no servidor - essa vulnerabilidade trivial persistiu por anos em algumas tecnologias).

Claro que é possível colocar seus arquivos na pasta configurada
para servir recursos estáticos - abaixo da mesma há uma correspondência entre o caminho passado na URL e a estrutura de diretórios `/static/...` - e como isso é feito pelo framework, as brechas possíveis já estão bem resolvidas.

Mas o mais normal nesses casos é ter uma imagem gerada pela aplicação, de
forma dinâmica - seja a cada acesso, seja um gráfico gerado a cada
intervalo de tempo, etc... nesse caso, entra a ideia da view - 
A função `serve(request, caminho_do_arquivo)` pode ser usada na sua view para servir um arquivo diretamente (importe-a com `from django.contrib.staticfiles.views import serve`).

O caminho do arquivo pode estar associado a um ID da imagem no banco de dados - e nunca ser exposto na URL, se você preferir

Comment: Por outro lado, servir o arquivo estaticamente, sem precisar passar pelo Python, sobrecarrega menos o servidor. Daria para usar reescrita de URLs para evitar expor o caminho real em disco.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta.

Não é como se num servidor wsgi moderno essa "passagem pelo Python" vá pesar qualquer coisa. Um django com configuração para produção deve chegar fácil a 3000req/s sem precisar otimizar nada - ele precisaria estar servindo muita imagem para isso fazer qualquer diferença em carga para o servidor. No entanto, URLs estáticas podem ser cacheadas em várias camadas diferentes da estrutura, inclusive em CDNs, então sim - URLs estáticas tem sua vantagem, se as mesmas  imagens forem servidas para vários usuários.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, sendo `arquivo` o objeto da sua **model** no [Django ORM](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/pt/django_orm/) e `caminho` o atributo `ImageField` ou coisa do tipo, você pode acessar o url direto dessa forma:

```
<a href="{{ arquivo.caminho.url }}" target="_blank">link</a>
```

([Django admin, static and media files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460028/confusion-in-django-admin-static-and-media-files/10460116#10460116))